# Code build error : Failed to upload artifacts: Invalid arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

In the aws codebuild service, I'm trying to build PHP project. As it does not create any artifacts, I've created the zip in post_build of buildspec.yml file. I need the artifact to deploy using codedeploy and codedeploy has no Revision Type as codecommit. Image for Yaml file has input is attached.

When the build is given on codebuild, UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS fails with error message as *"Failed to upload artifacts: Invalid arn"*. But according to logs, the artifact is found and gives *"UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS Success".*

Image is attached for the same. What is going wrong? Is it a bug or am I suppose to follow another procedure?

[Click here to see Yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpaG4.jpg)

[Click here to see Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQQA1.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

Check that the Codebuild project and the S3 bucket are within the same region, if they aren't you can get this error message.